# Javascript Sort not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I an issue with sorting div elements by price values. The functionality of the code works OK but it seems that it doesn't quite sort the numbers correctly.

As you can see from my jsfiddle when the button is pressed the number 21.35 comes after numbers 102.35 and 200.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here is the html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <button id="numBnt">Numerical</button>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="box">
        <h2>10.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>21.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>21.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>102.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>10.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>10.35</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>10.95</h2>  
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <h2>100.35</h2>  
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h2>100.05</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>200</h2>  
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <h2>5,510.25</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the javascript

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

And here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/370/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGrace/Vgavb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting these results is that your sort is not numeric, it is based upon canonical values of the numbers.

The reason why `21.35` comes after number `102.35` is because the digit `1` in `102.35` is smaller than the digit `2` in `21.35` and `0` in `200` is smaller than `1` in `21.35`.

**Fix:**
Parse to the numbers to float , before sorting

```
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text()) > parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text());
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/376/)

Comment: If you dont mind, How would you get around sorting them if they all started with a £ sign?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to parse to the numbers, use `parseFloat`.
2. You need to remove `,` from the text.

Code:

```
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text().replace(/,/g, '')) > parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text().replace(/,/g, ''));
});
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/C2heg/374/)

Demo:

```js
var $divs = $("div.box");


$('#numBnt').on('click', function() {
  var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text()) > parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text());
  });
  $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button id="numBnt">Numerical</button>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>10.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>21.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>21.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>102.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>10.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>10.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>10.95</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>100.35</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>100.05</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>200</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>5510.25</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi Could you tell me what do you mean by `not working`

Comment: Worked fine my friend :)

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi: His example is working fine.and the order is correct too